# Removing a sequence of items from a list in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of strings in java, that, visualised, looks something like this:

```
"Some text"
"Some more text"
""
"Line a"
"Line b"
...
""
"Line c"
"Line d"
```

In this list, I want to remove the triplet of `"", "Line c", and "Line d"` together, so the list would look like

```
"Some text"
"Some more text"
""
"Line a"
"Line b"
...
```

I have no idea how to do this. If I just remove the first occurence of each of the lines, the blank line before line a will be removed. Also, it is possible that line c is equal to either line a or line b, but it shouldn't be removed unless it is preceded by a blank line and followed by line d, so the removed items need to be exactly those 3 items, in exactly that order. Is there any way I could do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a `TwoLine` class.  Read the entire file into a `java.util.List` of `TwoLine` instances.  Delete the `TwoLine` instance that matches your input.  Write the entire `List` of `TwoLine` instances to a text file.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the list contains the sublist using `Collections.lastIndexOfSubList`, if it does get the last index and remove the elements iterating backwards begining from the largest index:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Some text",
                                            "Some more text",
                                            "",
                                            "Line a",
                                            "Line b",
                                            "",
                                            "Line c",
                                            "Line d"));

List<String> target = List.of("", "Line c", "Line d");

while (Collections.lastIndexOfSubList(list, target) != -1) {
    int lastIndex = Collections.lastIndexOfSubList(list, target);
    for (int i = target.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        list.remove(lastIndex + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the 3 next values, to know if you need to keep them or not

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Some text", "Some more text",
        "", "Line a", "Line b",
        "", "Line c", "Line d",
        "Line a", "Line b",
        "", "Line c", "Line d"));
for (int i = 0; i < a.size() - 2; i++) {
    if (a.get(i).equals("") && a.get(i + 1).equals("Line c") && a.get(i + 2).equals("Line d")) {
        a.remove(i);
        a.remove(i); // has everybody has move forward once, "Line c" if one forward too
        a.remove(i); // same
    }
}

System.out.println(a);
// [Some text, Some more text, , Line a, Line b, Line a, Line b]
```

---

The condition could also be

```
if (a.subList(i, i + 3).equals(List.of("", "Line c", "Line d")))
```